# What's a good and free ER diagramming tool for Linux that is approachable via a web interface?

Tags: linux, utilities, web, database, open-source

A web based ER diagramming tool.
One that you can install on Linux and afterwards approach it via a web interface.

- *Preferably Open source.*
- *Optional: connectivity with the database.*

Comment: Apparently draw.io (www.draw.io) is the tool of choice. You can download the client and run it locally or you can use their server side draw.io.